# Factors to be considered when re-engining aircraft

Tags: jet-engine, military, commercial-aviation, aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-certification

What parts of the aircraft need to be adjusted / refitted / added when fitting new (different type) of engines?

Also what what kind of re-certification regarding airworthiness etc. will be necessary?

Comment: This may depend a great deal on how different the engines are. Could range anywhere from basically no changes to huge redesign. Did you have any specific case in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the question just popped up when i was heard about the B-52 and then started thinking about how it would for example be done for the A340-600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends greatly on the engine. However, given the 737 MAX situation, I'll assume you mean re-engining with larger, more efficient engines. This still leaves a lot of room for interpretation- what aircraft are we working with? Something like the 757, with tons of ground clearance? Or something like the 737, with very little clearance? I'll answer both.

In the first scenario, re-engining a 757, there's not a WHOLE lot that needs to be changed. The engine mount/pylon, wing structure (to account for a heavier engine), and maybe the FADEC. That's really all I can think of. Maybe the fuel system.

The second scenario is where things get interesting. If you want to avoid a 737 MAX style situation, you'll need to extend the landing gear legs and find some way to stow them. If you can't find anywhere on the airframe that's beefy enough to accept that, then you'll have to find an ideal spot and reinforce it. Then change everything that I mentioned in the first scenario.

I'm no aerospace engineer, and I'm sure I'm missing countless things here, but these are all the major things that I can think of.